# Understanding the proof of an application of Banach principle of contraction.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces, contraction-operator

> **Theorem** $:$ Suppose $(X,d_X)$ is a metric space, $(Y,d_Y)$ is a complete metric space, $f : X \times Y \longrightarrow Y,$ $\exists K \lt 1$ such that $d_Y (f(x,y), f(x,y')) \leq K d_Y (y,y').$ Then there exists unique continuous function $\varphi : X \longrightarrow Y$ such that $\varphi (x) = f(x, \varphi (x)),$ for all $x \in X.$

> **Proof** $:$ For each $x \in X,$ $f_x : Y \longrightarrow Y$ be defined by $f_x (y) = f(x,y),\ y \in Y.$ Then by the given condition it follows that $f_x$ is a contraction map for each $x \in X.$ Hence it follows from Banach principle of contraction that $f_x$ has a unique fixed point for each $x \in X$ (Since $Y$ is complete). This induces an implicit function $\varphi : X \longrightarrow Y$ such that $\varphi (x) = f(x, \varphi (x)),$ for all $x \in X.$ So it only remains to show that $\varphi$ is continuous on $X.$ For that we define $g_x : X \longrightarrow Y$ by $g_x (u) = f(u, \varphi (x)), u \in X.$ Then $g_x$ is continuous on $X$ for each $x \in X$ since it is the composition of the continuous map $u \longmapsto (u, \varphi (x))$ with $f.$ In particular $g_x$ is continuous at $x$ for each $x \in X.$ So for a given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $z \in X$ with $d_X (z,x) \lt \delta$ we have $$d_Y (g_x (z), g_x(x)) \lt (1-K) \varepsilon$$ or in other words for all $z \in X$ with $d_X (z,x) \lt \delta$ we have $$d_Y (f(z, \varphi (x)), f(x, \varphi (x))) \lt (1-K) \varepsilon.$$ Therefore for all $z \in X$ with $d_X (z,x) \lt \delta$ we have \begin{align*} d_Y (\varphi (x), \varphi (z)) & \leq d_Y(f (x, \varphi (x)), f(z, \varphi (x))) + d_Y (f(z, \varphi (x)), f (z, \varphi (z))) \\ & \lt (1-K) \varepsilon + Kd_Y (\varphi (x), \varphi (z)) \end{align*} This shows that for all $z \in X$ with $d_X (z,x) \lt \delta$ we have $$d_Y (\varphi (x), \varphi (z)) \lt \varepsilon,$$ proving that $\varphi$ is continuous at $x.$ Since $x \in X$ was arbitrarily taken it follows that $\varphi$ is continuous on $X.$

> This completes the proof.

**QED**

I have understood the above proof. What I think is that the above proof is independent of the choice of the metric on $X \times Y.$ Because in the entire proof the metric on $X \times Y$ is of no use. But our instructor says that $X \times Y$ is endowed with product metric. I can't agree with him. Am I missing something? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you obtain that $f$ is continuous on $X\times Y$? Does that follow from the assumptions? This is used at one point.

Comment: The mapping $u \mapsto (u,\varphi(x))$ is certainly continuous with respect to the product topology, but not with respect to any topology on $X \times Y$.

Comment: @Olivier Moschetta it has been assumed that $f$ is continuous on $X \times Y.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa continuity of $f$ is very much dependant on the topology on $X \times Y$ (which comes from a metric), and so this is where the metric on $X \times Y$ is being invoked.

Comment: If $X\times Y$ has the discrete topology for instance, then unless $X$ also has the discrete topology, $u \longmapsto (u, \varphi (x))$ will not be continuous.